# Flask, Bootstrap Cards, and Jinja Templating

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I would like for my Bootstrap Cards to display horizontally instead of vertically but I am finding that I must declare a new "col-sm-4" each time I want the next card to show horizontally. The problem with this is if I try and do this inside the  Jinja "for" loop it just repeats the same card. Is there a way to iterate through the data like a "while" loop but for Jinja?

Here is the relevant Python code:

From "feeds.py" using feedparser package:

```
def get_news(publication="bbc"):
feed = feedparser.parse(RSS_FEEDS[publication])
articles_bbc = feed['entries']
return articles_bbc
```

And here is the relevant Flask code for this from "views.py"

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    articles_bbc = get_news("bbc")
    articles_cnn = get_news("cnn")
    articles_google = get_news("google")
    return render_template('index.html', articles_bbc=articles_bbc[:3])
```

And last the relevant html-bootstrap and Jinja2 code:

```
<div class = "row" style="background-color: lightgray;">
            <div class = "col-sm-4">


         <h5>Headlines from the BBC</h5>




                    {% for article_bbc in articles_bbc %}
                        <div class="card" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                            <div class="card-body" style="background-color:lightcyan;">


                                {%  if article_bbc.image %}
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ article_bbc.image }}" alt="Card image cap">
                                {% endif %}
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{article_bbc.title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">{{article_bbc.summary}}</p>
                                    <p>{{article_bbc.published}}</p>
                                    <a href="{{ article_bbc.link }}" class="btn btn-primary">Click for full article</a>
                            </div>



                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshots on how it's coming now and how you'd like it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Proper placement of the "for" loop ahead of the "col-sm-4" corrected it!